# How to Populate listview using arraylist from first activity

Tags: android

I am trying to populate Listview in to second activity getting data from first actvity passing arraylist.i have the arraylist values in the second activity but i am getting error "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.example.abc.test.RowItem",below is my code that i tried-----

THIS IS FIRST ACTIVITY -----

```
 addclient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View v) {

                                             Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


                                             for (int i = 0; i < itemsListView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
                                                 if (itemsListView.getChildAt((i)) != null) {
                                                     ArrayList<ArrayList<RowItem>> addyExtras = new ArrayList<>();

                                                     addyExtras.add(rowitems);

                                                     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                                                     Intent intent = new Intent(InvoiceMainActivity.this, Invoice_EditActivity.class);

                                                     intent.putExtra("mylist", addyExtras);
                                                     intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                                     startActivity(intent);

                                                    finish();
                                                 }
                                         }
                                             });
```

---

THIS IS SECOND ACTIVITY WHERE I AM TRYING TO POPULATE LISTVIEW ----------

```
public class Invoice_EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {

             @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_invoice__edit);
            TextView[] items = new TextView[4];
            TextView Qty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Slno);
            TextView Desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.one);
            TextView Price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.two);
            TextView Amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.three);

            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
            ListView itemslistview1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            Bundle value = getIntent().getExtras();
            String value1;

            ArrayList<RowItem> gtList = (ArrayList<RowItem>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist");

    //            ArrayAdapter<RowItem> adp = new ArrayAdapter<RowItem>(Invoice_EditActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, gtlist);
              MyListAdapter adp = new MyListAdapter(Invoice_EditActivity.this, R.layout.activity_row,gtlist);

                adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                itemslistview1.setAdapter(adp);
      }

    }
```

---

```
public class RowItem implements Serializable{

    private String qty;
    private String desc;
    private String price;
    private String amount;

    public RowItem(String qty, String desc, String price,String amount) {
        this.qty = qty;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.price = price;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public String getqty() {
        return qty;
    }
    public void setqty(String qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    public String getprice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setprice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getamount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setamount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
 }
```

---

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> implements Serializable {

Context context;

public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        ArrayList<RowItem> items) {
        super(context, resourceId,items);
        this.context = context;
        }

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView qtyview;
    TextView descview;
    TextView priceview;
    TextView amountview;

}
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);----->>Error 


        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.qtyview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Slno);
            holder.descview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.one);
            holder.priceview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.two);
            holder.amountview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.three);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.qtyview.setText(rowItem.getqty());
        holder.descview.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
        holder.priceview.setText(rowItem.getprice());
        holder.amountview.setText(rowItem.getamount());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

---

```
10-11 14:50:48.321  14138-14138/com.example.abc.test E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.abc.test, PID: 14138
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.example.abc.test.RowItem
            at com.example.smerasuvan.invoice.MyListAdapter.getView(MyListAdapter.java:42)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2823)
            at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1174)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18586)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18586)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:2019)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:487)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18586)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18586)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18586)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18586)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18586)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18586)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2897)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18586)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2277)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1331)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1573)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6682)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your FIRST ACTIVITY, you are passing object of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<RowItem>>` to `MyAdapter.java` but in constructor of `MyAdapter.java` you are receiving other type `ArrayList<RowItem>` :

```
 ArrayList<RowItem> addyExtras = new ArrayList<>();
 addyExtras.add(rowitems);
```

EDIT :

In your adapter, you should copy `ArrayList` in constructor :

```
private ArrayList<RowItem> mList;

public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
    ArrayList<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId,items);
    this.context = context;
    this.mList = items;   // This line
}
```

Please provide your first activity full code if error is still coming

Thank you

Comment: m stuck here for last 3 days ,i have listview of multiple items in 1st activity but i couldn't pass listview all items to 2nd activity in listview.

Comment: Please check EDIT in answer

Comment: thanx i'll give a try today